iptables Masquerade Rule Applying To Some Incoming Connections But Not All
Description
I have an IP Tables rule NAT rule that I am attempting to apply to incoming connections. I have an OpenVPN server running on an EC2 instance using sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

I am able to connect to the VPN box via it's public IP and it's private IP.
I am able to connect to EC2 instances in private subnets with only their private IPs
I am able to connect to the RDS instance from other ec2 instances in the VPC.
I am not able to connect to my RDS DB via the VPN box.
I am not able to connect to my RDS DB via my local laptop routing through the OpenVPN connection.

My core issue is that some of my outbound traffic is correctly being masqueraded to 10.21.0.0/16 which is my VPC's CIDR on the ens05 interface and some traffic is trying to go out via the OpenVPN tun0 interface on 10.8.0.1. I don't know why this is.
Full NAT List
ubuntu@ip-10-21-6-191:~$ sudo iptables -L -v -t nat --line-numbers
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 9740 packets, 782K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        7   476 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    any     ip-10-8-0-0.us-west-2.compute.internal/24  anywhere

tcpdump For ssh To ec2
This is just here to show that traffic is being sent as the private IP address for outgoing traffic of the ec2 instance and coming in as 10.8.0.2 for the inbound traffic of the OpenVPN Server
$ sudo tcpdump -v -A -n -i any dst 10.21.162.20 and port 22
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
06:13:23.505062 tun0  In  IP (tos 0x48, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    10.8.0.2.53847 > 10.21.162.20.22: Flags [SEW], cksum 0xdc1a (correct), seq 2279926992, win 65535, options [mss 1400,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2189220490 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
EH.@..@.@..=
...
....W.....................x.......
.|..........
06:13:23.505108 ens6  Out IP (tos 0x48, ttl 63, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    10.21.175.81.53847 > 10.21.162.20.22: Flags [SEW], cksum 0x2cbe (correct), seq 2279926992, win 65535, options [mss 1400,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2189220490 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
EH.@..@.?...

tcpdump For psql Connection To RDS
This is here to show that traffic is coming in on 10.8.0.2 and leaving as 10.8.0.2. Both in and out are against tun0 instead of against ens05 which is my actual private interface.
sudo tcpdump -v -A -n -i any port 5432
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
06:13:43.704192 tun0  In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    10.8.0.2.53850 > 10.21.187.190.5432: Flags [SEW], cksum 0x7db8 (correct), seq 2202549979, win 65535, options [mss 1400,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2513283422 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
E..@..@.@.j.
...
....Z.8.H>.........}......x.......
...^........
06:13:43.704244 tun0  Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    10.8.0.1.53850 > 10.21.187.190.5432: Flags [SEW], cksum 0x7db9 (correct), seq 2202549979, win 65535, options [mss 1400,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2513283422 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
E..@..@.?.k.
...
....Z.8.H>.........}......x.......
...^........
06:13:44.704362 tun0  In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    10.8.0.2.53850 > 10.21.187.190.5432: Flags [S], cksum 0x7a8f (correct), seq 2202549979, win 65535, options [mss 1400,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 2513284423 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
E..@..@.@.j.
...
....Z.8.H>.........z......x.......
...G........

Routes On VPN Server
ubuntu@ip-10-21-6-191:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.21.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens5
0.0.0.0         10.21.160.1     0.0.0.0         UG    200    0        0 ens6
0.0.0.0         10.21.160.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1003   0        0 ens6
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.21.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     100    0        0 ens5
10.21.0.0       10.8.0.2        255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.21.0.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens5
10.21.0.2       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens5
10.21.0.2       10.21.160.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   200    0        0 ens6
10.21.160.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     1003   0        0 ens6
10.21.160.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    200    0        0 ens6

iptables Rules Applied
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i ens5 -o tun0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i tun0 -o ens5 -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i ens5 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT

Attempted Rules That Didn't Work
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE

